# is this class within a class?

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have a div element in html page as follows.

```
<div class="Item1 Item2"></div>
```

**Item1** is the class and rule for its rule can be defined using following syntax.

```
.Item1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 5px solid white;
}
```

Is the **Item2** also called class? Can I apply its style just like a regular class?

```
.Item2 {
    width: 1px;
    height: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Both classes are independent, its not like `Item2` is a subclass of `Item1` - you could use it elsewhere by itself.

Comment: @PaulSnow because this is a pretty easily googlable css concept

Comment: Probably because you could've tested this in as much time as it took you to post.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev sounds like his question is at least in part about terminology. Testing would not help him learn this. Reading a beginner tutorial on html/css? *That* would be a good idea.

Comment: well I did googled it but since I wasn't sure terminology I wasn't sure if I am looking for the right thing. Sorry if I caused inconvenience for you guys

Comment: @ZachL "Can I apply its style just like a regular class?" -- That could easily be tested. Testing them together, separately, in different orders... like Ilya's fiddle in an answer's comment below. Besides, he asked why it was voted down, so I gave my opinion on why. It wasn't to be rude.

Comment: Understood Mike. I replied to your comment somewhat blindly, then re-read and understood your intentions, and edited my comment. I was just trying to justify OPs question a bit. It bums me out when I see new SO users attempt to ask a question but just get down-voted to oblivion. Glad this one got turned around and recieved some good info!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute `class="Item1 Item2"` specifies that the element belongs both to class `Item1` and to class `Item2`. The value of the [`class` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-class) is by definition a set of class names separated by whitespace. The order of the class names there is not significant.

So there is no nesting of classes.

This means that in CSS, the element matches both the selector `.Item1` and the selector `.Item2`.

In the example given, both rules would then be taken into consideration, and any conflict would be resolved by the normal rules of the [cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html). Other things being equal (as opposite to, say, having one rule in an author style sheet and the other one in a user style sheet, or having one of the rules inside a `@media` rule), a conflict of assigning a value to a property in both rules will be resolved in favor of the rule specified later. The resolution is by property, not for entire rules; so in the example case, the declaration that sets `border` will always be applied (unless overriden by something outside these two rules).